# How to read text inside <title> tag using Selenium and Java?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, page-factory

I've got some webpage and I'm looking for `title` tag with FindBy annotation (PageFactory.initElements is present in constructor of the class):

```
@FindBy(tagName = "title")
private WebElement titleTag;
```

After that I'm trying to get "some text" with WebElement method `titleTag.getText()`. The part of HTML code is common: `<title>some text</title>`. But I got absolutely no output - literally. Have tried to compare result with `null`, `""`, `\n` and even `\0`  - it's always `false` comparation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use @findBy for this. Just use `driver.getTitle()`